# Alternatives to storing variables globally

Tags: python

I am starting out with Python now, working on the Learn Python The Hard Way, on exercise 36. I want to create a good game, and learn some more techniques before moving on with the next exercise. I haven't approached the subject of Classes and Object yet, yet I want to see if I can do something that would be a bit more complex than a standard first 'choose-your-own-adventure' game.

I want to collect four different keys in 'Ganon's Lair', and then use those four keys to open a door in the 'main-hall'. I already have quite some of it worked out (not elegantly), but I still need to figure out how to store keys without them getting erased. An unelegant way is to assign them as global variables, such as I do here.

```
def grass_room():
global key1
grass_instructions = """As you enter the lair of the grass room, you see
                        a spider hanging on the ceiling, with his
                        big eye focused on you. You could grab your 1.slingshot,
                        or perhaps 2.make a run for the green-coloured key under his
                        tail?"""
    print grass_instructions
    gohma_boss = raw_input("> ")
    if gohma_boss == "1":
        print "You shoot him in the eye, he falls down and dies. You grab the key, and return."
        key1 = True
    main_hall("not_empty")
    else:
        print die("You die.")
    main_hall("not_empty")
```

Any suggestions for different ways to 'save' this key across functions, besides making them global?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want some variable or variables to be shared between functions, there are a few ways to do it:<sup>*</sup>

1. Pass each variable's value into every function as an argument, and return it from every function as part of a return tuple.
2. Wrap all of the values up in some structure, like a `dict` that you can look each thing up in by name, so you only have one value to pass and return.
3. Make the values attributes of an object, and turn the functions into methods of that object's type.
4. Use a closure, which I won't bother to explain because I'm sure you haven't learned about closures yet.
5. Use globals.

The Pythonic way to do this is definitely #3, but you haven't learned about classes yet. In that case, I'd just use #5, as you're already doing.

And when you learn about classes, coming back and modifying this script to use a class instead will be a great exercise.

---

<sub>* In fact, under the covers, options 3-5 are all pretty much syntactic sugar for option 2… but don't worry about that.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, I will experiment with these tonight :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make your `key` datatype a list or a dict and pass the `key` list/dict into each key-changing function. Since lists and dicts are mutable, changes made to the `key` list/dict in one function will be seen in the calling scope and in any subsequent functions that `key` is passed to.